# UPDATE Query is not updating record in Access Database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database, ms-access

Can anyone take a look at my code and tell me what is wrong? I'm trying to update the values but the Access database isn't updating, even though my method is parsing the query.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((string)Session["sFlag"] != "LI")
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        strUserId = (string)Session["sUserId"];
        txtUserId.Text = strUserId;
        txtName.Text = (string)Session["sName"];
        txtAddress.Text = (string)Session["sAddress"];
        txtEmail.Text = (string)Session["sEmail"];
        txtTel.Text = (string)Session["sContactNo"];


    }
}
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    strUserId = (string)Session["sUserId"];
    if (txtName.Text != "")
    {
        String strFName = "cFullName";
        String strFValue = txtName.Text;
        UpdateCustomer(strFName, strFValue);
        Session["sName"] = txtName.Text;
    }
    if (UFlag == "T")
    {
        Type strType = this.GetType();
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(strType, "Success", scriptSuccessUpdate);
    }


}

public void UpdateCustomer(string strFName, string strFValue)
{
    OleDbConnection mDB = new OleDbConnection();
    mDB.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source="
         + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/WMA_Proj.accdb");
    mDB.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd;
    String strSQL = "UPDATE Customers  SET " + strFName +
        " = @newValue WHERE cUserId = @userId";
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, mDB);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@newValue", OleDbType.Char).Value = strFValue;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@userId", OleDbType.Char).Value = strUserId;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    UFlag = "T";
    mDB.Close();

}
```

}

This is my Access Database table (image) as well.

[Access Database Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVzbA.png)

Comment: Do you mean that `UpdateCustomer` method does not update the database? Please show that method as well.

Comment: @ZoranHorvat Yes, the UpdateCustomer method does not update the database. The code is at the bottom of the code table.

Here is a screenshot of it if it's not viewable: http://puu.sh/sLBoh/4ccb2b659d.png

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't scroll down...

Comment: @ZoranHorvat It's alright, hope you can help! Thanks!

Comment: OleDbType.Char is 1 char without size. Probably you want to use OleDbType.VarWChar

Comment: @Steve doesn't seem to work either. :(

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected by the command. Try to read its return value with _int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()_ if the value is 1 then you are updating a different database than the one you look at. If the return is zero then there is no record that matches the where condition

Comment: Also be sure to not overwrite your database with the Property _Copy To Output Directory_ set to _Copy always_ or _Copy If newer_

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public void UpdateCustomer(string strFName, string strFValue)
    {
        OleDbConnection mDB = new OleDbConnection();
        mDB.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source="
             + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/WMA_Proj.accdb");
        mDB.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd;
        String strSQL = "UPDATE Customers  SET cFullname= @newValue WHERE cUserId = @userId";
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, mDB);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newValue", strFName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId",strFvalue);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        UFlag = "T";
        mDB.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It still parses through without updating the fields on my database. :(

Comment: try using `LIKE` instead of `=` like this
`String strSQL = "UPDATE Customers  SET cFullname= @newValue WHERE cUserId LIKE @userId";`